# Interpretar propiedad de una consulta como color de fondo en CSS

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]estoy trabajando en Laravel, blade  y necesito que al momento de realizar una consulta aparezca un cuadro con el color que le corresponde a una persona.

Tengo la tabla Cinturones con los campos
id: id_cinturones
descripcion_color:que guarda el nombre del color, ejemplo amarillo
color_html:guarda el color amarillo pero en html #FFE000

y la tabla persona que esta relacionada a la tabla Cinturones
id_persona
id_cinturones
nombre_persona
Quiero que al momento de mostrar los datos en la consulta en ves de aparecer la palabra amarillo, salga es el color amarillo
[image: tabla con los datos a mostrar sin el color]

```
<thead>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Apellido</th>
                        <th>Fecha Nacimiento</th>
                        <th>Sexo</th>
                        <th>Fecha de Ingreso</th>
                        <th>Cinturon</th>
                        <th>Accion</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach ($listado as $lista)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $lista->nombres }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $lista->apellidos }}</td>
                                <td>{{ date('d-m-Y', strtotime($lista->fecha_nacimiento)) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ (isset($lista->sex->descripcion) )? $lista->sex->descripcion : '' }}</td> 
                                <td>{{ date('d-m-Y', strtotime($lista->fecha_ingreso)) }}</td>
                               
                                <td style="background-color: {{ $lista->color_html }} " >{{ (isset($lista->cinturon->descrpcion) )? $lista->cinturon->descripcion : '' }}</td>
                                <td><a href="{{ route('fichaOvk') }}" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="fichaOvk">
                                    ↑ Ver</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
```

Comment: Agrega tu código de la vista por favor

Comment: ¿Cómo se llama la columna que guarda el color?

Answer (score 0):

- Tendrás que colocar el estilo *inline* es decir dentro de la etiqueta HTML
- A la propiedad `background-color` le asignaremos la propiedad que nos recupera `$lista` y que contiene el color en hexadecimal

Quedando de esta forma:

```
<td style="background-color: {{ $lista->propiedadX }}">{{ (isset($lista->cinturon->descripcion) )? $lista->cinturon->descripcion : '' }}</td>
```

Donde **`propiedadX`** es la columna de tu tabla que almacena el valor del color que deseas se imprima.

Comment: Saludos, gracias, pero sigue saliendo solo el nombre mas no el color,.

Comment: Debería ya de salir yo acabo de hacer un ejemplo en local, edita y muestra como lo intentaste hacer

Comment: Si estás guardando el color en hexadecimal?

Comment: Actualice el código, agregue la linea como tu dices, y subí la imagen de la tabla del hexadecimal de los colores